# Prolog: Resolvent/Resolution solver and recursion

Tags: list, recursion, prolog

Given 2 lists of positiv and negativ literals (representing clauses) I want to to get all possible Resolutions of these 2 clauses.

```
resolution([pos(X)|T],[H2|T2],R):- select(neg(X), [H2|T2],L),union(T,L,R).
resolution([neg(X)|T],[H2|T2],R):- select(pos(X),[H2|T2],L),union(T,L,R).   
resolution([H|T],[H2|T2],R):-resolution(T,[H2|T2],R).
```

This works for the first literal of the first list ([H|T]) but for after that due to how I wrote the recursion I lose the Head of the list after every recursion so that I don't get the whole union of my 2 original list but the union of the second list and the the subset of the first list after the deleted literal.

I couldn't figure out how I (try to) do a resolution for every element of the first list with the second whilst keeping all elements of the first list.

My idea is something like this:

```
resolution([[_]|[pos(X)|T]],[H2|T2],R):- select(neg(X),[H2|T2],L),select(pos(X),[[_]|[pos(X)|T]],Q),union(Q,L,R).
resolution([[_]|[neg(X)|T]],[H2|T2],R):- select(pos(X),[H2|T2],L),select(neg(X),[[_]|[neg(X)|T]],Q),union(Q,L,R). 
resolution([[_]|[neg(X)|T]],[H2|T2],R):-resolution([[[_]|[neg(X)]]|T],[H2|T2],R).
```

Trying to shift the element I am using for the resolution while keeping my list how it was but this doesn't work at all at the moment.

What the upper codes outputs:

```
?-resolution([pos(1),neg(3),pos(4)],[neg(1),pos(3),neg(5)],R).
R = [neg(3), pos(4), pos(3), neg(5)] 
R = [pos(4), neg(1), neg(5)]
```

(resolution with pos(1),neg(1) and neg(3),pos(3))

What it I want it to output:

```
?-resolution([pos(1),neg(3),pos(4)],[neg(1),pos(3),neg(5)],R).

R = [neg(3), pos(4), pos(3), neg(5)]
R = [pos(1),pos(4), neg(1), neg(5)]
```

Keeping the pos(1) of the first list.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"Shifting" an element to the "result" list can be done by using the list constructor `[_ | _]` in the "result" parameter as well, i.e., changing the last clause of your original program to:

```
resolution([pos(X)|T],[H2|T2],R):- select(neg(X), [H2|T2],L),union(T,L,R).
resolution([neg(X)|T],[H2|T2],R):- select(pos(X),[H2|T2],L),union(T,L,R).
resolution([H|T], [H2|T2], [H | R]) :-
    resolution(T, [H2|T2], R).
```

And there you go:

```
?- resolution([pos(1),neg(3),pos(4)],[neg(1),pos(3),neg(5)],R).
R = [neg(3), pos(4), pos(3), neg(5)] ;
R = [pos(1), pos(4), neg(1), neg(5)] ;
false.
```

This isn't perfect, for what if `H` is already present in `R`? It would be duplicated in the result. So maybe change to this:

```
resolution([pos(X)|T],[H2|T2],R):- select(neg(X), [H2|T2],L),union(T,L,R).
resolution([neg(X)|T],[H2|T2],R):- select(pos(X),[H2|T2],L),union(T,L,R).
resolution([H|T], [H2|T2], Resolvent) :-
    resolution(T, [H2|T2], R),
    union([H], R, Resolvent).
```

It's a bit of a pity that this loses the tail recursivity of the predicate.

For whatever it's worth, I don't see why you bother with recursion at all. What you are trying to do amounts to *select*ing an element from a list and keeping all other elements around. Your implementation of this, with the small fix from my first version, is basically an unfolded version of `select/3` itself. Why not go full `select/3`? Like this:

```
resolution(ClauseA, ClauseB, Resolvent) :-
    select(Literal, ClauseA, RestA),
    literal_opposite(Literal, OppositeLiteral),
    select(OppositeLiteral, ClauseB, RestB),
    union(RestA, RestB, Resolvent).

literal_opposite(pos(X), neg(X)).
literal_opposite(neg(X), pos(X)).
```

This is actually pretty close to a textbook definition of resolution.